# Unable to load default credentials in node.js google translate

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions, google-translate

I need to translate some text in node.js using google translate. I end up getting the following Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials%20for%20more%20information.%20%20%20%20%20at%20/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js:316:2) to get more details. This problem has costed me more than 48 hours. I have followed all the instructions in that link but problem still persists. Please someone point what is it that I've missed.

Error log:

> ERROR: Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
>   https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
>   for more information.
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js:316:21
>       at /user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/googleauth.js:346:7
>       at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:70:30)
>       at self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Request.onRequestError (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/translate/node_modules/request/request.js:878:8)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)

```
 function translateText(Text, Target) {
  // [START translate_translate_text]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const Translate = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// Instantiates a client
const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: projectId,
});


// Translates some text into Russian
translate
  .translate(Text, Target)
  .then(results => {
    const translation = results[0];

    console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);
    return translation;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: did you find the issue?

Comment: importing const translate = require('google-translate-api'); worked